# Intercept http and add headers - IONIC

Tags: ionic4, angular-http-interceptors

I'm running a Ionic 4 app which contains an http interceptor to add some loading between the requests.

I also have a credential service which validates whether there is a token in my storage or not.

this is my interceptor

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        this.requests.push(req);
        this.loaderService.isLoading.next(true);
        return new Observable(observer => {
            const subscription = next.handle(req)
                .subscribe(
                    event => {
                        if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
                            this.removeRequest(req);
                            observer.next(event);
                        }
                    },
                    (err: Error ) => {
                        this.alertservice.info(err.message, 'id1');
                        this.removeRequest(req);
                        observer.error(err);
                    },
                    () => {
                        this.removeRequest(req);
                        observer.complete();
                    });
            // remove request from queue when cancelled
            return () => {
                this.removeRequest(req);
                subscription.unsubscribe();
            };
        });
    }
```

It works, but when I'm trying to add the following lines, it stops working and redirects to my error page and consoles nothing, I can't track it.

```
    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        //console.log(this.credentialService.credentials.token);
        // console.log(authToken);
```

Can anyone help me understand why does it happen, and how to fix?

Comment: Let us know the code of your credentialService

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out and feel stupid,

`this.credentialService.credentials` was null since there is none before logging in, so the  interceptor sends me to error section, to fix, I first validate if it's not null, then add headers properly:

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        let clonedReq: any;
        if (this.credentialService.credentials !== null) {
            const authToken = this.credentialService.credentials.token;
            clonedReq = req.clone({headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', authToken)});
        } else {
            clonedReq = req.clone({headers: req.headers.delete('Authorization')});
        }
    {...}
```